# Mongo DB updated, but old info rendered

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, mongoose, passport.js

I am new to using the MEAN stack, and am trying to implement a user service. I want the user to be able to edit information such as their display name.

With the following code, I can see in the Mongo database that the change is being made correctly, but when I log req.user, I see it is displaying the non-updated version, and thus the update is not being rendered.

Please help!

```
var router = require('express').Router();
router.route('/users/:user_id/changeName')
    // Update user's display name
    .post(function(req, res) {
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.user_id, { $set: { name: req.body.newName }}, function(err, user) {
            console.log(req.user);
            console.log(req.body.newName);
            res.render('profile.ejs', { user: req.user });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Where does `req.user` get added in the first place?

Comment: I am using the passport.js Local Strategy to sign up users.

Comment: Oops, should have looked at the tags for this question. My bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't include any information about how `req.user` is being set, but if you're hitting your `User` collection to populate `req.user` for each request, then you'll have the most up to date user for your *next* request*.

If you were to simply `res.render` using the `user` object returned in the callback, you'd see the updated user:

```
res.render('profile.ejs', { user: user });
```

---

* In practice, you probably wouldn't want to hit your `User` collection for every request. Ideally, you'd have some session middleware that would cache the `user` object for the duration of the user's session. In that case, you'd need to update the session's reference to the user after updating the document in mongo.